# Nodejs Sails command line not working

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, sails.js

I'm working on a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04.  I have tried installing nodejs and sails via a number of methods, starting with the standard apt-get repositories, and then moving on to some other PPAs, but I get the same problem every time.

After successfully installing sails (sudo npm -g install sails) I attempt to run 'sails new testProject' and nothing happens.

When I run 'which sails' I get /usr/bin/sails... It seems that sails was installed but I have no way to run it.  Tried under root, and using sudo... kinda hacked away at it with no success.  I've followed several install guides and this is my result every time.  Nodejs seems to be working fine.

Once again, I'm on a vanilla install of Ubuntu 14.04

Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure why, but uninstalling node and following the guide on the sails.js site worked...

sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install nodejs

sudo npm -g install sails

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm what version of node and npm you have installed in your system?

```
node --version
npm --version
```